# Velocity of efflux when fluid is itself moving

Tags: fluid-dynamics

In efflux velocity given by [Torricelli equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torricelli%27s_law):

$$ v^2=2gh $$

what is reference frame for this $v$. Is it fluid or ground? I am just a high school level student, so please forgive my ignorance.

Answer (score 1):

The velocity $v$ is the velocity relative to the container and the fluid in it. That is, the fluid in the container is taken to be at rest, so $v$ is the velocity increase as the fluid is forced through the hole.

Torricelli's law is simpler than you (probably) think. It just uses conservation of energy to say the increase in kinetic energy must be equal to the decrease in gravitational potential energy. If you consider some small part of the fluid with a mass $m$ then as it falls a distance $h$ the decrease in gravitational potential energy is:

$$ \Delta U = mgh $$

And the increase in kinetic energy as the water accelerates to a speed $v$ through the hole is:

$$ \Delta T = \tfrac{1}{2} mv^2 $$

Since total energy has to be conserved these must be equal, and equating them gives:

$$ v^2 = 2gh $$